# jQuery ajax load information based on ID

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I want to use .load to change a div's text based on another page which pulls in items from the database. Essentially I have Ajax/popup.aspx?pID=23 which brings back a plain html file with a h2 and a

text

that i'll use .load to swap text out of a div. Heres what I have at the moment:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($(".CompanyType").length > 0) {

            $('.CompanyType').click(function () {
                $(".BuildingSize").empty();
                $(".BuildingSize").load("Ajax/popup.aspx" + "?pID=" + *WHAT TO PUT HERE*);
            });
        }

    });
```

My issue is that I'd normally use something like $(this).attr("value") to declaire the pID as i've only ever done it from dropdown lists. How can I asisgn a value to an image. (companyType is an image)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an HTML5 `data-*` attribute, something like this:

```
<img src="yourimgsrc" class="companyType" data-id="yourpID"/>
```

Then, in your code you'd do:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.CompanyType').click(function () {
        $(".BuildingSize").empty();
        $(".BuildingSize").load("Ajax/popup.aspx" + "?pID=" + $(this).data('id'));
    });
});
```

Note that I've removed the length check in your code because it's unnecessary - jQuery handles that for itself. I also don't think you need to `empty()` the element(s) before calling `.load()` - it should replace with, rather than append, the loaded content.

Answer (score 0):

if you got a `<input type="hidden" id="myIdHidden" val="23" />`

you can :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($(".CompanyType").length > 0) {

        $('.CompanyType').click(function () {
            $(".BuildingSize").empty();
            $(".BuildingSize").load("Ajax/popup.aspx" + "?pID=" + $('#myIdHidden').val();
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this

```
$(".BuildingSize").load("Ajax/popup.aspx" + "?pID=" + $(this).attr("id"));
```